# What could cause my neural network model's loss increases dramatically?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

I am training a network to solve a regression problem using Keras. During training, the loss of my model goes directly from 7 to more than 300000 dramatically. Here is the training output:
[image]

Here is the loss picture:
[image]

I wonder what could be the cause of this problem? Thanks

Comment: What optimization algorithm are you using? And what are the hyper-parameters (step-size, momentum etc.) of the respective optimization algorithm?

Comment: Sorry I forgot that, I use Adam as the optimization algorithm. The parameters are: learning rate=1e-4, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, just saying what i have seen, a few things could cause this:
1. learning rate. if it's too large, it could cause rising loss; just make it smaller, magnitudes smallers
2. in case of RNN, it could all blow up, weights, gradients, loss; there's paper published dealing with that.